# How the FileOutputStream write properties file don't lost information

Tags: java

I found something wrong when I write the Properties file by using `FileOutputStream`.

```
public synchronized static void setProperties(String file,String Properties,String value)
{       

    try {
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        Properties proper = new Properties();
        proper.load(is);
        proper.setProperty(Properties.toUpperCase(), value);
        is.close();

        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        proper.store(os,"Update the file:"+Properties); 
        os.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Look at the two lines below:

```
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
proper.store(os,"Update the file:"+Properties);
```

When the first line executed, the file will be empty, until the second line execute finished. Now, I assume the second line will execute within 3 seconds. During this period, the program crashed or another reason lead to the file to be unsuccessfully written. I will get an empty Properties file when I'm running my program next time. Anyone can tell me how to prevent this kind of situation to occur?

I changed my program like below, Seems it more better than before. At least I won't get a empty properties file, Thanks all guys.

```
public synchronized static void setProperties(String file,String Properties,String value)
    {       

        try {
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
            Properties proper = new Properties();
            proper.load(is);
            proper.setProperty(Properties.toUpperCase(), value);
            is.close();
            proper.store(new FileOutputStream(file+".tmp"),"Update the file:"+Properties);  //Prevent empty file
            File old = new File(file);
            File tmp = new File(file+".tmp");
            if(tmp.exists() && tmp.length()>0)
            {
                old.renameTo(new File(file+".old"));
                tmp.renameTo(new File(file));               
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: 1. If the program crashes, you cant do much other than having a listener in the beginning of your function to remove the file if there is one already. 2. If there is another reason (I presume exceptions), then just handle it in `Catch` block and remove the file if it is generated.

Comment: You can't. Crashes will happen. The best you can do is write to a .tmp file and then do a couple of renames, but even that can fail between renames.